# Multiple string/ pattern matching in R

Tags: r

I want to look for individual character strings [Sequences], in another data.frame [Database] that has 500+ rows.

For example:

```
Sequences<-c("AzzY","BbDe")
Database<-c("TTUAzzY","aaa","DBbDe","CAzzY")
```

Ideally, the code would iterate through each row of [Database] to find if there is a match with one of the [Sequences]. From the example above, there would be 2 matches for "AzzY" and 1 match for "BbDe". I would like this count to be added in a new column of [Sequences].

Many thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Your example data is not set up correctly.  Are they vectors?  data frames? lists?

Comment: @RichardScriven I have tried `grep(pattern = "AzzY", x = Database, value = TRUE)` but this just prints the output for each match in the console. I also need to manually add in each Sequence, rather than having code iterate over the database. They are factors within a data.frame

Comment: You should look into the Biostrings package.

Comment: @RichardScriven Database is the data.frame that I wish to find how many occurences of individual character strings, in Sequences, there are.

Comment: How about `Map(grep, Sequences, Database)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require("dplyr")
Sequences=c("AzzY","BbDe")
Database=c("TTUAzzY","aaa","DBbDe","CAzzY")

df=as.data.frame(sapply(Sequences, function(x) grepl(x,Database)))
stats=df %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
cbind(Sequences,as.numeric(stats))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sequences=c("AzzY","BbDe") 
Database=c("TTUAzzY","aaa","DBbDe","CAzzY")

sapply(Sequences, function(x) length(grep(x, Database)))
# AzzY BbDe 
#    2    1
```

Comment: This answer also worked, I am unsure how to vote for both answers as they both achieved what I set out to do. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to "flatten" the `Database` vector and search in that.

Here's that idea in practice with the efficient "stringi" package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_fixed(stri_flatten(Database), Sequences)
# [1] 2 1
```

You can pretty-up the output and add names if you want with `setNames`:

```
setNames(stri_count_fixed(stri_flatten(Database), Sequences), Sequences)
# AzzY BbDe 
#    2    1
```